# is it possible to load a jpg/png image into a TbitBtn or a TSpeedButton?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I need to display an image in a button, so that it is visually easier for the user to know what the button is for instead of reading its text.

as far as I can tell `TBitBtn` and `TSpeedButton` are buttons that can show an image, but I do not know anything about it and I would like to know if it is possible to have a .JPG or .PNG file and load that image into the button so that it displays it.

Comment: In case you're interested loading glyphs from JPEG or PNG in design time, see this [ancient article from Dr. Bob](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/property.htm) where he suggests creating custom property editor - `TPictureEditor`. It can be easily extended with JPEG and PNG. This way you can convert any image format to TBitmap in design time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`TBitBtn`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Buttons.TBitBtn) and [`TSpeedButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Buttons.TSpeedButton) only support BMP images, not JPG/PNG. You would have to convert the JPG/PNG images to BMP (which can be done in code by loading the images into [`TJPEGImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Imaging.jpeg.TJPEGImage)/[`TPNGImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Imaging.pngimage.TPngImage) first, and then `Assign()` them to the button's `Glyph`, which is a [`TBitmap`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap)).

In modern Delphi versions, [`TButton`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton) has an [`Images`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomButton.Images) property that you can assign any [`TCustomImageList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ImgList.TCustomImageList) to, and you can add PNG images to a standard [`TImageList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TImageList), or use a 3rd party PNG ImageList.

Otherwise, you can create your own owner-drawn button to draw JPG/PNG images directly.  Derive from `TButton` and override its [`CreateParams()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.CreateParams) method to enable the [`BS_OWNERDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/button-styles) style, and then handle the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/wm-drawitem) message  to draw the button however you want (this is what `TBitBtn` does).

Comment: Thanks @Remy, I am on Delphi Rio and your second sugestion Helped me a lot, that is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot assign a file to any of them. If you don't know a control, look up the manual to it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Buttons.TBitBtn and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Buttons.TSpeedButton

You have to do it indirectly: loading the file into a TBitmap, then assigning that to the button's Glyph property - the manual gives you one example thru http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/TBitBtnLayout_(Delphi)

Comment: You *can* load a BMP (not JPG or PNG) directly into the Glyph, you don't need to use an intermediate TBitmap

Comment: That's just "you don't need to use an intermediate variable" in a different colour and by that as obvious as `true= true` is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
The background color of the *TBitBtn* type button is transparent by default in some cases. Create a PNG image with a transparent background. Place a TImage component on the form. Load the PNG image into the Image property of the *TImage* component. Place the *TImage* component with the selected image in the place on the form where the *TBitBtn* button will be. Place a *TBitBtn* button on the image. That will be nice push button.

- Tested in Lazarus IDE, Linux. Works fine if the button and the image are placed on the component **TGroupBox**. If they was placed on other grouping components, transparent background of the *TBitBtn* isn't displayed.

Comment: Also need to disable the TImage.